# What does D mean in HTML DateTime Format "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD"

Tags: html

http://prasanjitmandal.blogspot.tw/2010/06/sharepoint-datetime-format-conversions.html

The above link says **Z** `indicates the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)`,

but what does last **D** mean in

> YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZ**D**

(I refer to the very last **D**; not the two **DD** which stand for `day-of-month`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D stands for designator. You can get more [explanation here](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime). So it stands for Time Zone **D**esignator

```
 YYYY = four-digit year
 MM   = two-digit month (01=January, etc.)
 DD   = two-digit day of month (01 through 31)
 hh   = two digits of hour (00 through 23) (am/pm NOT allowed)
 mm   = two digits of minute (00 through 59)
 ss   = two digits of second (00 through 59)
 s    = one or more digits representing a decimal fraction of a second
 TZD  = time zone designator (Z or +hh:mm or -hh:mm)
```

Answer (score 1):

'TZD' means ***Time Zone Designator***. See this link for an explanation:
[Explanation at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_time_datetime.asp)

Comment: Try to avoid linking w3schools. :)

Comment: Ok, but why? I followed the Stack rules and put the body of the explanation in the answer and then the reference... and which by the way I did before you posted YOUR answer.

Comment: You didn't get my point. Please check: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120621/w3fools-alternatives and http://blog.shahariaazam.com/why-you-should-avoid-w3schools-com-for-learning/ Hope then you will get what I meant! :)

Comment: You should probably read the post more carefully yourself. I have often found very useful information at that site. So, not really getting your point. Regardless... my answer contained the required information and only the required information and not all the other nonsense you included.... which as far as I am concerned is simply cluttering it up with non-essential info :)